# Building static linked Haxe cpp program

Tags: unix, haxe

I try to compile a commandline version of my Haxe program such that it can be used on other computers. These computers do not necessarily have Haxe installed - so I need to create a static linked program. I tried compiling such a version of my program with:

```
haxe -main mj.MJ -cpp outCpp -D HXCPP_M64 -D static_link
```

However the result is dynamically linked:

```
$ file outCpp/MJ
MJ: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, ...
```

and in consequence the executables are not working on computers that do not have these libraries installed:

```
$ ./MJ
./MJ: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by ./MJ)
```

So obviously "-D static_link" is not enough. I then added

```
package mj;

#if cpp
import cpp.link.StaticStd;
#end
```

(compare [Haxe - Create a C++ Stand-alone executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40930486/haxe-create-a-c-stand-alone-executable)) to mj/MJ.hx file. After re-executing:

```
haxe -main mj.MJ -cpp outCpp -D HXCPP_M64 -D static_link
```

the file is still dynamically linked ... what else do I need to do on Linux?

P.S.:

```
$ haxe -version
3.4.2
```

Comment: Fyi, it's spelled "Haxe", not "HaXe". It was changed around 5 years ago. :)

Comment: ah tks for the update

Comment: Regarding the actual question - I don't have the answer, but `mj.MJ` is probably leftover from a previous compilation, as `-D static_link` produces a statically linked _library_ (should be called something like `libmj.MJ.a`) and no executable at all.

Answer (score 2):

The Haxe standard library (HXCPP) on the C++ target used dynamically linked libraries for standard features (such as "zlib" and the "std" library) unless you used `-D static_link` in older versions, but starting with Haxe 3.4, these are always statically linked.

In current releases, `-D static_link` still affects third-party "NDLL" libraries, such as the [Lime](https://github.com/openfl/lime) library.

I personally use an older version of Linux (like Ubuntu 12.04 or 14.04) to build for distribution, due to differences in glibc on older Linux systems (or distributions that tend to use an older glibc, such as CentOS).

If you want, try experimenting with changing the [HXCPP toolchain for Linux](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/hxcpp/blob/master/toolchain/linux-toolchain.xml) to enable a static libstdc++ library `if="static_link"` and share the results here or on the Haxe community [forum](http://community.haxe.org).